# Can chain homotopy induce space homotopy at $E_\infty$ level?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, a-infinity-algebras

Space-level homotopy induces (co)chain homotopy, but I've never heard of the converse. I am not sure if it is simply not true?

However, for good enough spaces (finite type nilpotent), [Mandell proved that](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/E-infinity+algebra) weak homotopy types are determined by cochain complexes as an $E_\infty$-algebras up to quasi-isomorphism. Does this suggest that there are (co)chain homotopies in the sense of $E_\infty$, such that all of them backward induce homotopies between maps between spaces?

Comment: I read this question as: "What does the functor $C^*(-;\mathbb{Z})$ from finite,type nilpotent spaces to E_infty algebras do on morphism sets?. Is it injective and or surjective?" and I think it is a good question.

Comment: In fact Mandell answers this question in his paper. This functor is split injective on morphisms. Moreover, for any map of $E_\infty$-algebras $f:C^*(Y)\to C^*(X)$, one can construct a map $g:X\to Y$ such that $H^*(g)=H^*(f)$ (but $C^*(g)$ is different from $f$ in general).

Comment: @GeoffroyHorel I don't have the paper by my hand. Does that include chain homotopies $f$, with a degree shift? Also.. though $H^*(g) = H^*(f)$, I think it's still weaker than the statement that f and g are homotopic..

Comment: chain maps that are not of degree 0 can't be compatible with $E_\infty$-structure. Yes I agree that $H^*(g)=H^*(f)$ does not imply that the two maps are homotopic. In fact there are in general many maps of $E_\infty$-algebras $C^*(Y)\to C^*(X)$ that are not homotopic in the $E_\infty$-sense to maps of the form $C^*(g)$ for $g:X\to Y$ a map of spaces.